# Creating a User Registration Page using MongoEngine

Tags: django, authentication, mongodb, mongoengine

I am currently working an a webapp, using mongoengine and django, which will require users to create an account from a registration page. I know MongoEngine has an authentication backend, but does it also include a registration form, etc..., like django itself does? If not, are there any example projects which show how to implement this? The only open-source mongoengine project I've found is django-mumblr, but I can't find the examples I want in it.

I'm not interested in alternative options, such as MongoKit or mango for handling authentication.

I am just getting started with django and mongoDB, so please excuse my lack of knowledge. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried it out yet, but https://github.com/lig/django-registration-me by http://twitter.com/#!/lig1 looks like it could be a good bet.